# Reading values from a file with a different amount of values per column, C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I try to read values from a data file. However, it has a different amount of values per column which I need to extract.

The list of values looks like this:

```
8
11
0        0   -50
1000     0   -50
2000     0     0
0      500     0
500    500     0
0     1000   -50
1000  1000     0
2000  1000   150
```

With the code below I can store all values in the array but I want to store the 8 and the 11 seperatly. Furthermore should the first column (0 to 2000) be stored in one array, the second one (0 to 1000) in a second array and the third one (-50 to 150) in a third array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "PROGRAM PIPE NETWORK" << endl;

    //Read input data file
    int n;
    double *array;

    cout << "How many data sets do you have?\nDatasets: ";
    cin >> n;

    ifstream infile("pipedata.dat");
    array = new double[n];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        infile >> array[i];

    return 0;
}
```

I hope some of you can help me and please try to not write a general answer. I am quiet new in this topic.
Greetings.

EDIT 1:

An other attempt is the following, however it works sometimes but I also get erros with data adresses or heap difficulties. Sometimes it works but most of the time my program just stops working.

```
int main()
{
cout << "PROGRAM PIPE NETWORK" << endl;

// Read input all data files
int n; double *input;
int limit_x, x; double *array_x;
int limit_y, y; double *array_y;
int limit_q, q; double *array_q;
int n_nodes, n_tubes;

cout << "How many data sets do you have?\nDatasets: ";
cin >> n;

ifstream infile("pipedata.dat");
input = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) infile >> input[i];

// Assign input values to their variables
// Number of nodes and number of tubes
n_nodes = input[0];
n_tubes = input[1];

cout << "Input values" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << input[i] << endl;
}
cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "X-Values" << endl;
// Node data x-values
x = n_nodes;
limit_x = n_nodes * 3;
array_x = new double[x];
for (int i = 0; i < limit_x; i += 3)    array_x[i] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < limit_x; i+=3)      array_x[i] = input[i+2];

for (int i = 0; i < limit_x; i+=3)      cout << array_x[i] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine with "input" but not with array_x. Also I want to do the exact same thing with 5 other variables. I know it isnt the best solution but I realy dont understand why it does not work.

Comment: Read the first two rows separately, outside of the loop.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file array" for some almost duplicates.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) infile >> array[i];`  Arrays start at index 0, not 1.

Comment: Isnt it possible to start with an random  " i " for arrays? For example i = 2?

Comment: There is nothing in the language preventing you from assigning anywhere inside an array or beyond.  If you have an array, `int a[2];` and use `a[10] = 5;`, the language will allow this.  You are writing beyond the array which is *undefined behavior* and anything can happen, from aborts to overwriting exiting variables or overwriting executable code.

Comment: Yes just offset the array "double*array2 = array-2;"  then array2 starts at 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the complications are, but here is an example:

```
std::vector<int> array_1;
std::vector<int> left;
std::vector<int> middle;
std::vector<int> right;
int temp;

// Read two numbers into an array
data_file >> temp;
array_1.push_back(temp);
data_file >> temp;
array_1.push_back(temp);

// Read columns of data into separate arrays
int left_value, middle_value, right_value;
while (data_file >> left >> middle >> right)
{
  left.push_back(left_value);
  middle.push_back(middle_value);
  right.push_back(right_value);
}
```

The above is one example of many.  It is not optimized.

Another example uses `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`, which would comply better with the alignment of the rows.

**Edit1: Line by line processing**

```
std::string text_line;
std::istringstream parser;

// Read a line from the file
std::getline(data_file, text_line);

// Extract the numbers from the line:
parser.str(text_line); // Initialize the std::istringstream with the text line.
int value_1 = 0;
parser >> value_1; // Extract the first number of the first line.

// Read the second line from the file
std::getline(data_file, text_line);

// Extract the numbers from the line:
parser.str(text_line); // Initialize the std::istringstream with the text line.
int value_2 = 0;
parser >> value_2; // Extract the first number of the second line.

// After reading 2 lines, the file pointer should be pointing
//   at the 3rd line.
// The data format changes at the 3rd line with 3 numbers per line.
// Let's use an array this time, one per column.
const unsigned int  ARRAY_CAPACITY = 256;
int column_1[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
int column_2[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
int column_3[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
unsigned int row = 0;

// Read until the data stream fails, usually at EOF.
while (std::getline(data_file, text_line))
{

  // ** Very important, check for overflow before using array**
  if (row >= ARRAY_CAPACITY)
  {
     // Either reallocate and copy old array or ...
     // Crash the program.
     std::cerr << "Array capacity is too small.\n";
     exit(1);
  }

  // Initialize the parser
  parser.str(text_line);

  // Extract the first value and place into array, directly.
  parser >> column_1[row];  

  // Likewise, the next columns.
  parser >> column_2[row];
  parser >> column_3[row];

  // Advance the column index to the next row (line)
  ++row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I do not understand completly how your code works. Where are the arrays and how do I tell the program to start putting values in the arrays starting from the third line? What does "push_back" mean? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm using `std::vector` instead of arrays because arrays can't expand during runtime.  For example, if you have an array of 3 and read in a 4th value, the 4th value goes past the array.  So before reading the 4th value, a new larger array must be allocated, old values copied, old array deleted.  If you allocate a 1000 slot array, and only read 10 items, you are wasting memory space.  The `std::vector` resolves these issues.

Comment: The lines `data_file >> temp` read the first two integers.  They happen to be be the first and second lines.  Thus the `while` loop starts on the the third line.  If you really need to read per line (and not per integer), use the `std::getline` to read a line into an `std::string`.  Use `std::istringstream` to extract the numbers from the string.

Comment: See my update, I have added the code for using arrays and extracting data per line.

Comment: I checked this code and I think gives the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried something else by myself with allocating arrays and pointers  (array = new double [x]). I edited my original post. @ThomasMatthews

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click on the check mark.

Comment: Do I have to include some headers or something from the library? Somehow " parser " and " getline " are red underlined.Unfortunately my visual studio is in german but the error is something like " an incomplete type is not valid "  for parser and " No instance of overloaded functions fits the list of arguments " for getline.

Comment: You need a basic class in C++.  Search your favorite reference for `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`.  Find out which header files to include for them.  Similarly for `std::string`.